# Trying to figure out fb auth flow for my website

Tags: php, facebook, oauth

I need to be able to display the login to FB button to a new user, which I got to work, but I also need it to display if he/she does not accept permissions. However, I need the button to go away and output something else when permissions are given. It also has to reappear when the user has logged out of FB. The issue is that `$user = $facebook->getUser();` is established even when he just logs into my site w/o permissions.

Answer (score 0):

How do you trigger the login screen php or JS ? is you do with JS you can do this below, In that way you know if the user granted the permissions or not.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login',function(response) {
   if(response.session) { //checks if session is true
      alert('logged in');

      if(response.perms) { //checks if perms is true = permissions are granted
         alert('perms granted');
      }
      else { //if perms is false = no permissions granted
         alert('no perms');
      }
   }
   else { //if something goes wrong
      alert('login failure');
   }
});
```

After that you will need to check if the user didn't remove the permissions from his profile settings, this can be done this way :

```
$permissions = $facebook->api("/me/permissions");
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response Michael. Right now my code is set up where I would generate the login button using Javascript then I'd try/catch api call to user permissions and if the count of permissions is equal to what it's supposed to be it redirects to another page, if not it stays on the current page. Can I incorporate this into the javascript flow above. Aditionally, where do I insert this code for it to take effect. Right now I place it after fbAsyncnit and all that works is the login failure prompt which shows up but only when I click deny permissions. None of the other prompts pop up.